# TLS1.2, weak cypher suites and PCI DSS V3.2.1 compliance

Tags: tls, pci-dss, cipher-selection

Are below cypher suites, which are part of TLSv1.2:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

are a reason to fail PCI scan? I can't find anything related to this particular set apart from the fact that they are considered weak. PCI DSS insist on TLSv1.2 but from what I'm seeing nothing around cypher suites.
Pointers to any relevant part of documentation would be more than welcome.

Thank youpoci

Comment: *"... apart from the fact that they are considered weak."* - where did you get this claim from? These ciphers are not weak.

Comment: Steffen, they'll come up weak in a Nessus or Qualys (ssllabs) scan because RSA doesn't have ephemeral keys.  Change DHE or ECDHE and it'll be fine.

Chris, no idea if addressing this is required for PCI compliance.

Comment: Was this an official PCI ASV scan or just a general scan? In a general scan I could see a recommendation to move to ephemeral keys, but I don't believe that should come up in a PCI ASV scan which is just checking 'strong cryptography' (based on NIST).

Comment: @withoutfire Thanks for your input. This is also my understanding but I'm looking for some evidence of this.

Comment: If it is an ASV scan it will say so - and if you have an ASV that is rejecting these cipher suites then I'd love to know - I'll put you in touch with someone at the PCI SSC who would be interested to see the scan output.